# How to Scrape Data from a Map Using Python (Fail to Click a Layer)?

Tags: python, selenium

[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POySG.png)

I try to scrape data from the map on the [website](https://aisgzk.kz/aisgzk/ru/content/maps/).
In particular, I need the data from the table shown on the right side of the attached image.

To reach the table manually one needs to click:

1. the region name (the left column written in Russian) ->
2. subregion name ->
3. then layer on the map,
4. and the table pump up on the screen.

To implement the code I use the selenium library in Python.

I got stuck on step 3, failing to click a map layer to reach the table.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed any further.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

website = 'https://aisgzk.kz/aisgzk/ru/content/maps/'
path = 'D:\ML_project\driver\chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)

region_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-name = "Костанайская"]')
region_button.click()

subregion_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-name = "Алтынсаринский"]')
subregion_button.click()


driver.quit()
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use the python request library to get the that you need. Because that can be very easy to extract. 
https://f000.backblazeb2.com/file/ShareX2022/ShareX/chrome_IZUBA4U3Tm.png
https://f000.backblazeb2.com/file/ShareX2022/ShareX/chrome_2AfK6JvuFy.png
Have a look at this two photos. Chrome sends the request to the backend api to get the data for the table  when you click the layer. If u make http get to those api endpoints request with specific formdata then you can easily get your desired .
If you dont understand what I am talking about comment again. I will elaborate.

Comment: Thank you very much! You gave me a great hint!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was using the wrong library. Instead selenium one should use request.

The YouTube video helped me is [Always Check for the Hidden API when Web Scraping]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqtlR0y0suo

My final code looks:

```
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
from urllib3 import disable_warnings
disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

url_regions = "https://aisgzk.kz/aisgzk/Index/BuildRegionTree"

payload_regions = "sLang="
headers_regions = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Origin": "https://aisgzk.kz",
    "Referer": "https://aisgzk.kz/aisgzk/ru/content/maps/",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "sec-ch-ua": "^\^Not?A_Brand^^;v=^\^8^^, ^\^Chromium^^;v=^\^108^^, ^\^Google",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "^\^Windows^^"
}

response_regions = requests.request("POST", url_regions, data=payload_regions, headers=headers_regions, verify=False)

print(response_regions.text)
```